# Can we pause and continue download process using Dio Flutter Package

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, dio

Actually I want  **play/pause/retry** option for my video downloader(Both iOS and Android). Currently I am using **DIO** package. Here I can download and cancel the downloading process. But how can I pause and continue the download process.

Answer (score 0):

With dio response  you can use interceptors to look at the errors  and based on your error like no mobile connectivity you may retry or  resuming the download  and and cancel download you may use the `canceltoken`  parameter by dio.

Comment: You should elaborate further on your answer, give some example and make it more comprehensive